# What are better ways to check if externally hosted image file exists?

Tags: php, curl, fopen

I use the code below and it's working for me but most of us know we can't trust `fopen` because of it does not always work well on external files. So my question is what other methods can I use to check if an external url exists?

I know it can be done with [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) and I could check for image size but I was wondering how other coders would solve this and what is the best method to do this.

**Required:** If the image is available, echo the image code and if image is not available echo the text link code as in the working example below.

```
<?php
// Set the beyondsecurity.com image URL you want to connect to...
$url = "https://secure.beyondsecurity.com/verification-images/www.largevideotube.com/vulnerability-scanner-2.gif";
// Check to see if the beyondsecurity.com image URL exists by trying to open it for read only..
if (fopen($url, "r")) {
// echo the beyondsecurity.com image link if I was able to open the beyondsecurity.com image URL for read only..
echo '<a href="http://www.beyondsecurity.com/vulnerability-scanner-verification/www.largevideotube.com"><img src="https://secure.beyondsecurity.com/verification-images/www.largevideotube.com/vulnerability-scanner-2.gif" alt="Website Security Test" /></a>';
} else {
// echo a text link if it took to many time to open the file or if it wasn't there at all..
echo '<a href="http://www.beyondsecurity.com/vulnerability-scanner-verification/www.largevideotube.com">Website Security Test</a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: file_exists() works on remote servers to

Comment: Define 'better'. What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: @ Dagon: Yes I know but `file_exists()` also not always on externally hosted files..

Comment: "also not always on externally hosted files" say what now?

Comment: @ Hobo Sapiens: Nothing wrong with my code, it is working well in this case. I was just interested in other methodes and I believe there are better methodes that never fail for external files..

Comment: @ Dagon: Yes I know but `file_exists()` will not always work to check if externally hosted file exists

Comment: always worked for me, you have evidence that it will not alwasy work?

Comment: 1: safe mode, see php.net manual for `file_exists()` 2: it's possible to block `file_exists()` on the server that is hosting the file, don't know why but some webmasters do so. Sorry,  I don't remember an example site that is blocking some type of requests but yes it is possible

Comment: If you are going to be making requests to other servers to check on the status of a file, please be polite and use a [HEAD request](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4).

Answer (score -1):

I would make an HTTP Request and check the Response status code and Response headers. If you get a 200 response, that means that your request was okay. You can check the Content-Type header to see if the content is an image. Then you could do whatever you want with the response body, which for a 200 response would be the image. If you get a 4XX or a 5XX response, then something went wrong or the image can't be found. You could do this with cURL, or one of the awesome libraries out there for making HTTP Request/Responses like Guzzle.